# Let G be a finite group. Let N(H) denote the normalizer of a subgroup H. Let P be a p-Sylow subgroup of G. Prove that N(N(P)) = N(P).

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

So , $N(P)$ is a subgroup of $N(N(P))$  and $P$  is a subgroup of $N(P)$,Then using the fact that P is a sylow subgroup perhaps one could obtain some relations on the order of the $N(N(P))$ and $N(P)$ , and then there is also the fact that all Sylow subgroups are conjugate .

I can't think of any other way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Frattini's Lemma:

> If $G$ is a finite group and $H\lhd G$ with $P$ Sylow subgroup of $H$ then $G=N_G(P)H$

Applying this for $G=N_G(N_G(P))$ and $H=N_G(P)$ we have $N_G(N_G(P))=N_{N_G(N_G(P))}(P)N_G(P)=N_G(P)$